# Where to ask: "Must I use an emulator to use KakaoStory and WeChat on Windows 10?"

Tags: discussion

Which SE website fits [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1404022/993453)?

Comment: I don't think any SE sites will treat that as on-topic. You _may_ be able to post a variation to <https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com>

Comment: If you want to run any software on a platform that does not support it, you need some form of interface between the software and the OS, plus any required supporting software, and even then, it isn't guaranteed to work.  The general options are a compatibility layer, an emulator, or a VM.  The more options you take off the table, the slimmer your chances of getting it to work.  There isn't a canned solution.  If someone had done it, your Internet search would have spotted it.  Unless someone has posted a success story, any solution will be through trial and error.  (cont'd)

Comment: That doesn't lend itself to the kind of definitive answer appropriate for a Q&A site.  Since no software mechanism is guaranteed to work, this wouldn't be a good question even on Software Recs.  If you found a solution and couldn't get that to work, that might be on topic here.

Comment: [Site recommendation questions should be asked on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)